# progress dialog in for into a thread

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem, I have a for loop and a ProgressDialog and would like to see something like (10/5) where 10 is the total items to be processed by and for the 5 elements are currently being developed. I have this code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            for(int i=0; i<adapter.getTotalItems().size(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    index = i;
                                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyClass.this,adapter.getTotalItems().size()+"/"+index, );
                                    MyClass.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            progressDialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    });



                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                 catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1*2000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            MyClass.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        });

                    }
            }).start();
```

Comment: That once processed all the elements the progress dialog remains. Instead you should be dismiss

Comment: don't use a thread. Look for `AsyncTask` or probably even just a `CountDownTimer`.

Comment: Don't use thread. Instead of using thread please try like that example http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/07/downloading-file-using-event-of-dynamic.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t cancle the ProgressDialog every Time, just Change the Title like:

```
mProgressDialog.setTile(adapter.getTotalItems().size()+"/"+index);
```

That´s it.